# FluidSynth no sound (pyFluidSynth) on MacOS except in shell

Tags: macos, audio, midi, fluidsynth

I'm using pyfluidSynth on MacOS. I have FluidSynth working with sound using the shell, but in my python program there is no sound (and no error).
Any special configuration needed in FluidSynth configuration or in my MacOS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just setup pyFluidSynth on MacOS - had the same issue.

I fixed it by providing a sound driver in the Synth.start method:

```
fs = fluidsynth.Synth()
fs.start(driver='coreaudio')
```

Answer (score 0):

This clue help me to solve the same trouble on Raspberry Pi. Fluidsynth, by default, works with 'jack' audio driver, but 'alsa' was correctly configured, not 'jack'.

```
fs=fluidsynth.Synth()
fs.start(driver='alsa')
```

Comment: I do not see a relevant functional difference to the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55205641/7733418 Please [edit] and make more obvious what additional insight you contribute.